# Import array from external JS file into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I try to load an array from an external JS file into my HTML and have problems with that.

My js.js:

```
var temp_max = [4,9,2,5,8,4,2,10];
```

My HTML:

Note: Please download this file [DateJS](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs/blob/master/src/globalization/de-DE.js) and insert it into "DATE-JS"!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--CSS for layout-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <!--Date library for german date layout-->
    <script src="DATE-JS"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

        <br>
        <br>


    <div style="width:80%" position="absolute">

        <div class="header">

            <script>

                    for(var i = 0 ; i <8 ; i++)
                    {
                        var weekday=Date.today().addDays(i).toString('dddd');
                        document.write("<div id='div_weekday'>" + weekday + "</div>");
                    }

                    for(var i = 0 ; i <8 ; i++)
                    {
                        var day = Date.today().addDays(i).toString('dd');
                        document.write("<div id='div_date'>" + day + "</div>")
                    }

            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
background-color: rgb(86,86,85);
}

h1:after {
    content: " ";
    width: 70.5%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: rgb(228,203,153);
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 15px

  }

  .header {
    width: 100%;
}

.header > div {
    color: rgb(228,203,153);
  width: 12.5%;
  float: left;
  border: solid rgb(228,203,153);
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
  text-align: left;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.header > div:first-child {
  border-width: 1px;
}


#div_date {
  border: none;
  width: 12.5%;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  border-bottom: solid rgba(228,203,153,0.3);
  border-width: 0.5px;
  padding-right: 1%
}

#div_weekday {
  border: none;
  width: 12.5%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 1%
}
```

Here is a screenshot without importing the JS array.
[image: Structure]

So I want that my temp_max array values are displayed exactly above the German weekdays!

So above the first information: 'Donnerstag' the script should display the value 4 from the array and so on.

Please note that I want to export this array from an external JS-file, I am not able to write this variable into my HTML file!

I already tried to use

```
document.getElementById
```

but this does not work for me.

Comment: If you provide a working code snippet you most likely will get a proper answer, as of now it is very difficult to both understand and see what you mean goes wrong.

Comment: I am not able to write a proper JSFiddle code because I imported some libraries from DateJS with I can´t use for JSFiddle, also I can´t provide the database column..Do I have any other option to provide these files to you?

Comment: I would use the browser's dev. tools to "Inspect" and get the rendered code, and from there create a working code snippet.

Comment: I updated my question, please check again and dont forget to import the DateJS lib

Answer (score 0):

If the problem just in looping over the created divs, I think you can do this.
All what you need to change is just adding a different ids to your divs.
Just use `i` index in your ids.

Something like this:

Creation:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i <8 ; i++) {
    var weekday=Date.today().addDays(i).toString('dddd');
    document.write("<div id='div_weekday_" + i + "'>" + weekday + "</div>");
}
```

Updating data:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    document.getElementById('div_weekday_' + i).innerHTML = temp_max[i].weekday;
}
```